# Object not visible in Cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, camera, tracking

Basically I am working on a small project where i wanted to place a 3d mobile in a Footage.
I captured the footage which included the small reference pieces for tracking. I tracked the camera in blender itself and put my 3d mobile in the footage. I gave my very own environment texture.
Here's the image

[image]

I put it on cycles render. But after I render the image for testing.
The mobile didn't appear in the render.
[image]

I tried everything but i didn't get any solution.
Anyone's help will be useful.
I am extremely sorry if there is any kind of grammar mistake in my message.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question, and detail what you tried (it is hard to guess what you mean by "I tried everything") that is not working, and also show images of the render nodes, the material nodes for the missing object and show an image of the outliner.